# Ionic React how to use css properties

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework, ionic-react

I'm new to IonicReact and I don't know how to use css properties to that component.
For instance I'm using IonItem component but it not works

```
<IonItem lines="none" className={classes.ionItem}>
...
</IonItem>
```

It has default padding and highlight effect so I want to remove it but not sure how to do it.
I tried to using *useStyles()* and *CSSProperties* but not works.

It has custom css properties like --highlight-height, --inner-padding-start but not sure how to use them with useStyles and CSSProperties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const ionItem: CSSProperties = {
    width: '100%',
    '--padding-start': '0px',
}

let classes= useStyles();
<IonItem className={classes.ionItem}>...</IonItem>
```

It should work.